# In impala/hive, How can I extract the word before and after a specific keyword in a string?

Tags: string, hive, impala

I have a string column in impala called `text` that contains descriptions. I would like to get the words before and after a specific keyword.

Example:

- `text`= This is a great property right in front of the beach. The 50 **m2** apartment is divided into a bedroom....
- `keyword`= **m2**

desired result: two columns, `word before` = **50**  and `word after`= **apartment**

Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you describe your problem in more detail, please? E.g. by adding code or commands you've tried to solve it on your own. Please have also a look to the Help Center, especially regarding [asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [minimal examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`regexp_extract`](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-StringFunctions) to match words before and after `m2` and extract them seperately.

```sql
with t as ( select "This is a great property right in front of the beach. The 50 m2 apartment is divided into a bedroom" as text)
select 
    regexp_extract(t.text , "(\\w+)\\s+m2", 1) as word_before,
    regexp_extract(t.text , "m2\\s+(\\w+)", 1) as word_after
from t ;

+--------------+-------------+--+
| word_before  | word_after  |
+--------------+-------------+--+
| 50           | apartment   |
+--------------+-------------+--+
```